# Django: Annotate table with field across a M2M mapping to another table

Tags: sql, django

I want to get competition.name from a list of submissions.

In my setup, **competitions** and **teams** share a M2M relationship (with an associated **competition-team** object. Each competition-team pair can submit any number of **submissions**. I now have a dashboard page which I am trying to create a table of all submissions by the team accompanied by the respective competition's name. The output should look like:

```
| Submission Name | Submission Date etc. | Competition Name |

| Sub01           | 2020-12-30 2000      | Competition01    |
```

I have trouble retrieving the competition name from the submissions. Here are my models:

```py
class Competition(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```py
class CompetitionTeam(models.Model):
    competition_id = models.ForeignKey('Competition', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', db_column='competition_id')
    team_id = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', null=True, db_column='team_id')
```

```py
class CompetitionSubmission(models.Model):
    competitionteam_id = models.ForeignKey(CompetitionTeam, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='competitionteam_id')
```

I wish to annotate a set of **submissions** with their respective **competition names**. I tried with:

```py
submissions.annotate(competition_name=Subquery(Competition.objects.filter(id=Subquery(CompetitionTeam.objects.get(id=OuterRef('competitionteam_id')).competition_id)).values('name')))
"ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery."
```

I also tested with the following command:

```py
CompetitionSubmission.objects.prefetch_related('competitionteam_id__competition_id')
```

It runs but the command seems to do nothing. I will update this post with other methods I try.
Thank you.

*EDIT*

```
submissions.annotate(competition_name=Subquery(Competition.objects.filter(id=Subquery(CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(id=OuterRef(OuterRef('competitionteam_id_id'))).values('competition_id'))).values('name')))
```

Seems to work correctly.

Comment: `..CompetitionTeam.objects.get(..` have you tried replacing .get with .filter?

Comment: Haha yes actually! I'm now faced with different issues but I think its a step in the right direction. 
*EDIT* This seems to work, but I have yet to ensure if it is correct: 
"submissions.annotate(competition_name=Subquery(Competition.objects.filter(id=Subquery(CompetitionTeam.objects.filter(id=OuterRef(OuterRef('competitionteam_id'))).values('competition_id'))).values('name')))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse ForeignKeys directly using double underscores.

```
CompetitionSubmission.objects.values(
    'competitionteam_id',
    'competitionteam_id__competition_id',
    'competitionteam_id__competition_id__name',
    'competitionteam_id__team_id',
    'competitionteam_id__team_id__name',
    )
```

This will only produce a single database query. Django ORM takes care of everything.

P.S. I would avoid using '_id' in field names as Django model fields are supposed to be referring to related objects themselves. Django automatically adds extra attributes with '_id' that contains the related object's id. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation